# how to make a custom entity multilingual

Tags: 8, entities, i18n-l10n

I made a custom entity (ty drupal console). but i would also like to make this entity translatable. I enabled all 4 multilingual core modules but i don't see the "translate" tab in my entity nor can i enable translation form the "admin/config/regional/content-language" page (it says N/A), but i can show the language selector which as no real effect.

is it possible to translate custom entity, if so, how? what am i missing?

Answer (score 10):

You need the `translatable = TRUE` line in your `@ContentEntityType` annotation. You also need the `setTranslatable(TRUE)` line in your `BaseFieldDefinition::create` fields.

Comment: thanks a bunch, i looked everywhere for this information. you are my hero today :)

Comment: Do you not also need to specify the data_table in the annotation?

Comment: @RainderFeike and then Translate tab should be available out of the box? For me with above steps not. I have translatable title field + annotation

Comment: Do you have the core modules enabled? Content Translation and Language?

Comment: @RainerFake I've missed configuration at admin/config/regional/content-language from description, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for translating custom content entities - https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/translating-custom-entities

Make sure to enable translation support for your custom entity under 'Content Language' configuration.